# RXKotlin - How to receive single event

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-kotlin2

I am getting callback event from an object twice sometime thrice but I need to collect only one object that will be the latest one. Is it possible with RX kotlin?

Comment: Can you provide some code what you've done?

Answer (score 1):

If contents are **different**:

```
Observable.create<String> {
    it.onNext("One")
    it.onNext("Two")
    it.onComplete()
}
.lastOrError()
.subscribe { data, error ->
    Log.d("Log", data)
}
```

If contents are **same**:

```
Observable.create<String> {
    it.onNext("One")
    it.onNext("One")
    it.onComplete()
}
.distinctUntilChanged()
.subscribe {
    Log.d("Log", it)
}
```

Or combine them together:

```
Observable.create<String> {
    it.onNext("One")
    it.onNext("Two")
    it.onNext("Two")
    it.onNext("Two")
    it.onComplete()
}
.distinctUntilChanged()
.lastOrError()
.subscribe { data, error ->
    Log.d("Log", data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your observable is emitting multiple times but you only need the latest one then you can use `Observable.blockingLast()` to get that item and ignore the rest.

Similarly, you can user `Observable.blockingFirst()` to only get the first result.

Note that both of these will block the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

Single behaves similarly to Observable except that it can only emit either a single successful value or an error (there is no "onComplete" notification as there is for an Observable).

```
        Single.create<String> {
            it.onSuccess("one")
            it.onSuccess("two")
            it.onSuccess("three")
        }.subscribe(
            {
//            ON Succuess
            },
            {
// on error
            }
        )
```